# possible options for Cell Mapping in Google Sheet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, mapping

I have a Google sheet, has two worksheets with cell "A1" as drop down:

1. Completed
2. Not Completed
3. Show All

I want to link both cells so that change in value of one cell will depict in other vise versa. I have been looking for the solution and found out that on selection event the app script can be triggered where I can manipulate values. however I could not figure it out the right solution.

In excel/word we can use XML to map values/controls. what is the alternative for this in Google sheets? there must be a way besides app scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I have a Google sheet, has two worksheets with cell "A1" as drop down:`, I understood your question is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet including 2 sheets like "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
- The cell "A1" of each sheet has a dropdown list including 3 values like `Completed`, `Not Completed`, `Show All`.
- For example, when the dropdown list of "Sheet1" is changed, you want to change the dropdown list of "Sheet2" to the same value with "Sheet1", and vice versa.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and please set your 2 sheet names to `sheetNames` and save the script.

When you want to test this script, please change the dropdown list of the cell "A1" of "Sheet" or "Sheet2". By this, the value of your selected dropdown list is copied to the cell "A1" of another sheet, and vice versa.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]; // Please set your sheet names.

  const { range, source, value } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  const idx = sheetNames.indexOf(sheetName);
  if (idx == -1 || range.getA1Notation() != "A1") return;
  source.getSheetByName(sheetNames[idx ^ 1]).getRange("A1").setValue(value);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the simple trigger is used. So, when you directly run the script with the script editor, an error like `Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Answer (score 1):

Syncing two cells in two spreadsheets:

I used the same sheet name and you have to put the other ssid in the ss spreadsheet and both have to be installable triggers

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('other ssid');//place ssid for other spreadsheet
    ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0').getRange("A1").setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

I created the validations manually

Comment: please don't mind, I am new to app script, what is `other ssid`? how do I assign it

Comment: You will require the function to be placed in the two spreadsheets.  Each `ss` must be for the other spreadsheet.

Comment: I am sorry if it was misleading, there are two sheets in one "google sheet". in term of Excel. there are two spreadsheets in one workbook.